# Parse output of a command, and store in var

Tags: bash

I have a command I'm looking to run:

```
echo "Performing unicornscan on:" $target
unicornscan -Ivv $target:1-65535 | tee enum/uniscan-alltcp.txt
```

This produces output like:

```
TCP open 192.168.0.102:443  ttl 128
connected 192.168.103.227:54487 -> 192.168.0.102:161
TCP open 192.168.0.102:161  ttl 128
connected 192.168.103.227:47765 -> 192.168.0.102:80
TCP open 192.168.0.102:80  ttl 128
connected 192.168.103.227:4267 -> 192.168.0.102:1884
TCP open 192.168.0.102:139  ttl 128
sender statistics 963.9 pps with 65536 packets sent total
listener statistics 131180 packets recieved 0 packets droped and 0 interface drops
TCP open                http[   80]     from 192.168.0.102  ttl 128
TCP open         netbios-ssn[  139]     from 192.168.0.102  ttl 128
TCP open                snmp[  161]     from 192.168.0.102  ttl 128
TCP open               https[  443]     from 192.168.0.102  ttl 128
TCP open        microsoft-ds[  445]     from 192.168.0.102  ttl 128
```

How can I parse this output to grab all the ip addresses in a *comma* seperated list like:
`80,139,161,443,445`

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to grab the IP addresses, or the ports? In the above, `80,139,161,443,445` appear to be ports.

Comment: Use `sed` to match the lines with `TCP open.*\[` and grab the number between `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a script that may solve your issue. This prints all of the output.

Follow these steps:

1. Open `answer.bash` (or whatever you want to name the script) in a text editor.
2. Type or paste the following:

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Store the command in a variable for easy changes
# Note: The command is not actually executed until the while loop
COMMAND="unicornscan -Ivv $target:1-65535 | tee enum/uniscan-alltcp.txt"

PORTS=()

# For each line:
while read line; do
        # The third token is either IP or protocol name with '['
        token=`echo $line | awk '{print $3}'`
        last_char_idx=$((${#token}-1))
        last_char=${token:$last_char_idx:1}
        # Case 1: It is the protocol name
        if [[ "$last_char" = "[" ]]; then
                # This is a protocol. Therefore, port is token 4
                port=`echo $line | awk '{print $4}'`
                # Shave off the last character
                port=${port::-1}
        else
                # token is ip:port. Awk out the port
                port=`echo $token | awk -F: '{print $2}'`
        fi
        PORTS+=("$port")
done < <($COMMAND | egrep "^TCP open")
# egrep is used to skip any lines that don't begin with TCP open
# 'tee' should still send full output to file

# Print all the ports we found
for p in "${PORTS[@]}"; do
        echo -n "$p, "
done
echo
```

3. Save the file.
4. Type `bash answer.bash`. Observe your desired output (hopefully!)

## Explanation

The script uses a `while` loop to go through the command line-by-line. Each iteration, the current line is set to the `line` variable.

In the while loop, I use `egrep` to get ONLY lines that begin with `TCP open`. I noticed that the third token of each of these lines either contains an IP:Port value, or a protocol name followed by the `[` character. The script assumes the latter case for anything ending in `[` and handles accordingly, using `awk` to get the port name from the fourth token. If it's an IP:Port pair, `awk` can also be used, with `:` as the field separator.

Each port that is obtained in this manner is stored in the PORTS array. At the end of the script, each value of the ports array is printed, resulting in the following output:

```
443, 161, 80, 139, 80, 139, 161, 443, 445,
```

You can pipe the output of this script into a file or variable, or store it in a variable right inside the script.

Please let me know how it works and if you have questions. Also, my apologies in advance for excessive use of subshell.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a ary
while read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ \[\ *([0-9]+)\] ]]; then
        ary+=("${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")
    fi
done < "file.txt"

ifs_bak="$IFS"  # back up IFS
IFS=,; list="${ary[*]}"
IFS="$ifs_bak"  # retrieve IFS

echo "$list"
```

- The regex extracts a numerical value between `[` and `]` and assigns `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` to it.
- Then the values are stored in an array `ary`.
- Finally `ary` is printed as a comma-separated value.